# Hadoop: no node available for block blk_-5883966349607013512_1099

Tags: hadoop

I am very new to Hadoop. I start Hadoop with the following command...

```
[gpadmin@BigData1-ahandler root]$ /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.1/bin/start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.1/logs/hadoop-gpadmin-namenode-BigData1-ahandler.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.1/logs/hadoop-gpadmin-datanode-BigData1-ahandler.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.1/logs/hadoop-gpadmin-secondarynamenode-BigData1-ahandler.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.1/logs/hadoop-gpadmin-jobtracker-BigData1-ahandler.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.1/logs/hadoop-gpadmin-tasktracker-BigData1-ahandler.out
```

When I try to -cat the output from the following directory, I get an error: "no node available". What does this error mean? How can I fix it? Or start debuging it?

```
[gpadmin@BigData1-ahandler root]$ hadoop fs -cat output/d*/part-*
13/11/13 15:33:09 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: No node available for block: blk_-5883966349607013512_1099 file=/user/gpadmin/output/d15795/part-00000
13/11/13 15:33:09 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain block blk_-5883966349607013512_1099 from any node:  java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain current block
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you start the datanodes before the namenode.

When the datanodes start before the namenode starts, the datanode services try to check in to the namenode & fail saying `"namenode not found"`. Then once the namenode starts, it has no datanodes checked in, therefore it cannot find the node on which the block of data being accessed is located.

You should go through the script `start-all.sh` and make sure that the namenode starts before the datanodes.